# Is there a way to clean up subclass parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, parameters, subclass, superclass

I'm trying to work on using subclasses in JavaScript and I am using Marvel movies to do it. Here is my superclass:

```
class Episode {
  constructor(title, releaseDate, storyYear, phase, order, runtime, hero){
    this.title = title;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    this.releaseMonth = parseInt(releaseDate.split('/')[0]);
    this.releaseYear = parseInt(releaseDate.split('/')[1]);
    this.episodeType = "";
    this.storyYear = storyYear;
    this.phase = phase;
    this.order = order;
    this.runtime = runtime;
    this.hours = parseInt(runtime.split(':')[0]);
    this.minutes = parseInt(runtime.split(':')[1]);
    this.hero = hero;
  }
}
```

Now I have created 3 subclasses. One for Movies, one for TV Shows and one for "One Shots". This way I can add extra information such as TV Season, Episode, and which DVD the one shot is a part of.

```
  class Movie extends Episode {
    constructor(title, releaseYear, storyYear, phase, order, runtime, hero){
      super(title, releaseYear, storyYear, phase, order, runtime, hero);
      this.episodeType = "Movie";
    }
  }
  class TVShow extends Episode {
    constructor(title, releaseYear, storyYear, phase, order, runtime, hero, episode){
      super(title, releaseYear, storyYear, phase, order, runtime, hero);
      this.episodeType = "TV Show";
      this.episode = episode;
    }
  }
  class OneShot extends Episode {
    constructor(title, releaseYear, storyYear, phase, order, runtime, hero){
      super(title, releaseYear, storyYear, phase, order, runtime, hero);
      this.episodeType = "One Shot";
    }
  }
```

The issue I am seeing is if I add a constructor to the original Episode I have to go and add it to each of the subclasses as well. Is this the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Use an object as parameter

Comment: You could use `constructor(...args) { super(...args); this.episodeType = "Movie"; }`, but notice that adding parameters also affects (breaks?) the interface that involves the additional `episode` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bergi suggested you can use list of arguments instead of explicitly defining each argument, e.g.

```
class Episode{
   constructor(args)
   {
      this.args = args;
   }
}


class Movie extends Episode{
   constructor(args){
     args.episodeType = 'Movie';
     super(args);
   }
}

// The same for all subclasses
```

This way you get much cleaner code and avoid listing all the params everywhere. However, you lose implicit definitions of all arguments and may want to implement some constraints manually. e.g. throwing an error if `args.title` is undefined or empty.

Comment: In this, how would I access the args? If I created an Episode called ironMan. Would I access the title with ironMan.args.title?

Comment: yes, you can do it like that, or create a getter function.